# my autogrowing textarea doesn't auto minimize

Tags: jquery, textarea, autosize

an easy one for some of you. I found some code to make it autogrow but not automin. The reason I want to use my own code is because if i use a plugin it might not get updated for newer jQuery and i don't need a crazy amount of options (accompanied by extra code for them)... and for my current application i cannot risk it.

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e){
  e.e=$(this);e.h=e.e[0].scrollHeight,e.e.css('height','24px');
  e.e.css('height',e.h),e.e.css('max-height',e.h)
});
```

it grows just fine, but it does not work when i remove characters. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. To me it seems the *scrollHeight* is not being adjusted once characters are removed.

Comment: there are numerous more robust plugins for this

Comment: as mentioned i would like to avoid using plugins.

Comment: jQuery 3 broke a few plugins. I don't have time to have a conversation here. since you don't have an answer for this particular application: it is pointless for you to comment unless you are looking for easy "points".

Comment: well this isn't a code writing service for fixing stuff *"I found on internet"*. I was trying to be helpful and give you a suggestion that would have you up and running already

Comment: i never assumed that it was. You can see from the first post that it was clear what my intentions were.

To be helpful would be to meet the criteria of the request. I'll elaborate: a plugin would mean even more code than a few lines for the simple function.

observe: https://github.com/AndrewDryga/jQuery.Textarea.Autoresize/blob/master/js/jquery.textarea.autoresize.js

Comment: this is not an answer because it uses a plugin but its not as fat as other ones.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Auto-Grow-Of-Textarea-On-Typing-autoresize.html